# Firefox won't navigate to site on localhost when internet connection is broken

Tags: networking, firefox, internet-connection

I am serving a website from localhost, my `/etc/hosts` contains

```
127.0.0.1 foo.com
```

If I navigate to foo.com in Firefox, the site works...

...unless the Internet connection is down, then Firefox won't navigate to `foo.com`, it will report `Server not found`.

Other software (ping, elinks) can reach `foo.com` regardless.

How can I make Firefox realise it *can* still connect to localhost?

Comment: what version of firefox are you using? See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=967792. Seems there was a key added (network.dns.offline-localhost) to fix that issue, but it looks like it was added a while back. If you're on a really old version of firefox, try updating (or if on newer version, check that key in about:config).